# Why Zend Controller test doesn't render layout, but corresponding viewscript only

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

Could you please suggest if it is expected behavior that when testing Zend Controller with PHPUnit `$this->getResponse()->getBody()` returns only content of corresponding action's viewscript, but no layout?

If so, is it possible to turn on rendering of complete html - layout + viewscript?

Comment: Check the config file / section used for testing

Comment: The testing section is almost empty and has nothing except of different db config.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, it is normal that you do not have the layout in your Controller;

Indeed, the layout is call in postDisatch() of Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout's plugin and postDisatch() of plugins are calling after postDisatch() of Controllers.

To another question, I wrote a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688441/3351765) that can recover the layout filled after calling an other the controller and before calling plugins.

Maybe it can help you. :)